# A question about complex integration formula using Green's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Use the Green's theorem (complex form) to show that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-p}=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $p$ is outside $\gamma$} \\ 
 1& \text{if $p$ is inside $\gamma$}\\
\end{cases}$$

I proved this one by taking $z-p=re^{i\theta}$, but how could I prove it using Green's theorem?

Comment: should not assume that the curve is circle. This holds for all enclosed curves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double integral vanishes since the integrand is zero. If $p$ is outside then just apply the Green's result. If $p$ is inside then you may consider the integration domain to be inside $\gamma$ without a small circle around $p$ and replace integration over $\gamma$ to integration over this circle. Then you can apply what you have proved.

Comment: @Nyfiken...can you rough calculation i can processed..please

Comment: @suresh You may find it, for example, [here, Example 4, p. 5](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/Teaching/classes/425F05/Green.pdf).